# Add <span> below a <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn javascript, but I stuck on a very simple problem.
I tried a lot of things for 3 hours but without success.

I have to insert this span tag below the div "form-control-tag-inner" :

```
<span class="label label-default"><span class="text-">nick</span><span class="close close-tag" aria-hidden="true">×</span><input type="hidden" name="participants[nick]" value="nick"></span>
```

And the html code :

```
<div class="form-group" id="receiver">
    <label for="conv-dest">Receivers (Max 100)</label>
    <div class="form-control-tag">
        <div class="form-control-tag-inner">

        <!--- Here i need to insert span tag -->

        <input tabindex="1" type="text" autocomplete="on" class="filtre-tag" id="conv-dest" placeholder="Add">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that adds span along with ability to attach events to newly added content:

```js
var innerTag = document.querySelector('.form-control-tag-inner');
var innerInput = document.querySelector('#conv-dest');
var innerContent = document.createRange().createContextualFragment('<span  class="label label-default"><span class="text-">nick</span><span class="close close-tag" aria-hidden="true">×</span><input type="hidden" name="participants[nick]" value="nick"></span>');
innerTag.insertBefore(innerContent, innerInput);

// sample event, attached on newly added content
var innerCross = document.querySelector('.form-control-tag-inner .close');
innerCross.onclick = function(){
    console.log( 'click' );
    return false;
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id="receiver">
    <label for="conv-dest">Receivers (Max 100)</label>
    <div class="form-control-tag">
        <div class="form-control-tag-inner">
           <input tabindex="1" type="text" autocomplete="on" class="filtre-tag" id="conv-dest" placeholder="Add">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="form-group" id="receiver">
  <label for="conv-dest">Receivers (Max 100)</label>
  <div class="form-control-tag">
    <div class="form-control-tag-inner">

      <p>This is a paragraph <span style="color:#FF0000;">
         This is a paragraph</span>This is a paragraph</p>

      <p><span style="color:#8866ff;">
         This is another paragraph</span></p>

      <input tabindex="1" type="text" autocomplete="on" class="filtre-tag" id="conv-dest" placeholder="Add">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

refer above as example for using span tag.
If any other thing you looking please explain.

Thanks

Comment: I don’t think this answers the question on how to insert a div using js...

Answer (score 1):

Just another option.
You may also use `DOMParser()`, with that you convert simple HTML strings into DOM objects.

[DOMParser() Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```js
var span = '<span class="label label-default"><span class="text-">nick</span><span class="close close-tag" aria-hidden="true">×</span><input type="hidden" name="participants[nick]" value="nick"></span>',
    form = document.querySelector('.form-control-tag-inner'),
    nick = new DOMParser().parseFromString(span,'text/html').firstChild;
form.insertBefore(nick,form.firstChild);
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id="receiver">
    <label for="conv-dest">Receivers (Max 100)</label>
    <div class="form-control-tag">
        <div class="form-control-tag-inner">

        <!--- Here i need to insert span tag -->

        <input tabindex="1" type="text" autocomplete="on" class="filtre-tag" id="conv-dest" placeholder="Add">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```